# Can't query between databases in SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I have a SQL Azure Database Server and I need to query between the Databases but can't figure out how to accomplish this.

Here is the structure of my databases:

- **Server.X**

  - **Database.A**
  - **Database.B**
  - **Database.C**

In **Database.A** I have a Stored Procedure that needs to retrieve data from **Database.B**.  Normally, I would reference the database like `SELECT * FROM [Database.B].[dbo].[MyTable]` but this does not appear to be allowed in SQL Azure.

`Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Reference to database and/or server name in 'Database.B.dbo.MyTable' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.`

Is there a way to do this on the database end?

In the final version Databases A & C will both need data from Database B.

Comment: Did you find a solution or a way to acomplish it?

Comment: for those who wants a quick solution for that (when it comes to importing data), you can create a new table with the same structure that you wanna have, export the data from the other database and add to this new table.. After that you can use your logic for importing data (my case)

Comment: Quick fix: Remove `[Database.B].[dbo].`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

**Update:**

As per Illuminati's comment and answer, the situation has changed since this answer was originally accepted and there is now support for cross database queries as per https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

***Original Answer (2013):***
Cross database queries aren't supported in SQL Azure. Which means you need to either combine the databases to prevent the need in the first place, or query both databases independently and basically join the data in your application.

Comment: Vote for support http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/402636-cross-database-reference

Comment: Is this still the case? :o

Comment: @CaiusJard- This is still the case as of tonight, which is why I came across this question and answer.

Comment: What are the chances of it ever not being the case?

Comment: @PaulLambert soon enough: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-overview/

Comment: This is now supported. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/

Comment: Need More Votes to Support - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/33264520-allow-to-access-one-database-from-another-database

Answer (score 10):

Azure SQL DB is previewing Elastic Database Query feature at this point in time that will help you query among Azure SQL DBs with some limitations. You can get detailed information about the feature [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-query-vertical-partitioning/).