# Azure - Multiple database queries

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

How can I query multiple tables from multiple azure databases?

Imagine I have "customers" table in Database X and "sales" table in dabtabase Y and I want to join them in a query, how is it possible to do this in Azure?

Comment: Just to clarify: Are you specifically talking about Azure SQL Database service?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't Query between Databases in SQL Azure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284998/cant-query-between-databases-in-sql-azure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David is correct -- currently Azure SQL DB doesn't support cross-database joins.

Is it possible for you to combine the two databases into a single DB, but use separate schema to keep the namespaces of objects separate?  I am curious about the business reasons you are maintaining separate dbs.  You can reach out to me directly at Stuarto  Microsoft  com.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about Azure's SQL Database service, then no, you cannot have queries across two separate database instances. The queries are limited to the single database.

If you require queries spanning multiple databases, you'd need to install SQL Server on a VM.

Answer (score -3):

You can join them if they're hosted on the same server. Try this

```
SELECT a.userID, b.usersFirstName, b.usersLastName  FROM databaseA.dbo.TableA a inner join database B.dbo.TableB b  ON a.userID=b.userID
```

Comment: If the OP is referring to SQL Database service, this cannot be done.

Comment: While this is valid for SQL Server, it cannot be done in Azure.