# Calling functions of master DB from other DB on the same Azure SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have Azure SQL DB Server + one Azure SQL database on it. Within this DB I have functions which call some functions of master DB as a part of their logic.

Example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[EncryptByKey]
(
    @EncryptionKeyId nvarchar(1024),
    @ValueToEncrypt varchar(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(ENCRYPTBYKEY(Key_GUID(@EncryptionKeyId), @ValueToEncrypt))
END
```

Gives me an error:

> Cannot find either column "master" or the user-defined function or
>   aggregate "master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr", or the name is ambiguous.

If instead I try:

```
exec master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(123)
```

The error I get is:

> Reference to database and/or server name in
>   'master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr' is not supported in this version of SQL
>   Server.

Are there any solutions on how to use master DB functions from user's DBs on Azure SQL server?

Comment: Why do you use EXEC insted of SELECT? select master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(123)

Comment: @sepupic, please, read carefully. Example with exec is only used to get more proper error message. Select is not working either.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284998/cant-query-between-databases-in-sql-azure

Comment: @sepupic thanks for pointing this out, gonna read through the MS article mentioned on your link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use distributed database queries using three or four part names on SQL Azure.

For queries that span multiple databases in SQL Azure, you need to use elastic queries. For more information, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview) article.