# How to join two tables from different database in MS SQL Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have two different tables in two different databases. Need to join both the table and get results using query

1) **reports** - report_id, report_name, description

table reports is present in database 'A'

2) **report_owners** - report_id, report_owner

table report_owners is present in database 'B'

tried following query for joining the tables but it's throwing error ( **Reference to server and/ database is not supported in this version of SQL server**).

Query:

```
select * from [A].[dbo].['reports'] as all_reports
INNER JOIN
select * from [B].[dbo].['report_owners'] as all_owner
ON all_report.report_id = all_owners.report_id
```

Note: from Database 'A' have access for cross query functionality for database 'B'

Anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't query between databases in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284998/cant-query-between-databases-in-sql-azure)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [elastic queries](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/) to perform cross database queries. See the following example:

**Customerinformation (remote db)**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerInformation (CustomerID int identity(1,1) , CustomerName nvarchar(255));

DECLARE @i int = 1;
WHILE @i < 20000
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CustomerInformation(CustomerName)
VALUES ('Frodo');

SET @i += 1;
END
```

**On the database that will use the external table**

```
CREATE TABLE OrderInformation(OrderId Int identity(1,1), CustomerId int,Ordervalue int);


SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @i int = 1;
WHILE @i < 200 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO OrderInformation(CustomerId,Ordervalue)
Values (@I,111);

set @i += 1;
END

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  [dbo].CustomerInformation(
    CustomerID [int],
CustomerName nvarchar(255))
    WITH  
(  
    DATA_SOURCE = Stackoverflow  
);
```

**Query the remote table like this.**

```
SELECT o.OrderId, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
  FROM OrderInformation o
  JOIN CustomerInformation c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
 WHERE o.OrderId = 155
```