# Unresolveable Circular reference error when configuring multiple datasources in a spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I'm trying to configure two datasources in my spring batch application. One for batch metadata tables, and another for the business tables.

**Snippet from my application.properties file:**

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=

spring.batchdatasource.url=
spring.batchdatasource.username=
spring.batchdatasource.password=
spring.batchdatasource.driver-class-name=
```

**My batch config file:**

```
@Configuration
public class SpringBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

//  @Autowired
//  private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;


    @Bean(name = "batchDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.batchdatasource")
    public DataSource batchDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "primaryDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }


    @Override
    public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(batchDataSource());
//  factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setTablePrefix("schema1"+ ".BATCH_");
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
    }

   /* Job and step bean definitions here */
```

**My main class is the one annotated with `@EnableBatchProcessing`**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SpringBatchExample1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this `Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?` when trying to configure two datasources. It works fine when using a single datasource by autowiring(refer the commented out lines of code) instead of creating multiple beans.
Following is the exception snippet:

```
Error creating bean with name 'springBatchConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setDataSource' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDatasource': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

I looked up and found out this occurs when there's a dependency on a bean which is still not created or is being created. I just see it in the `createJobRepository` method where datasource is being plugged. I still face the error even if I don't have the `createJobRepository` method.

It seems like the requirement is for the datasource beans to be created before others. I tried using the `@Order` annotation, but no luck.

**EDIT:**

I tried the solution from @Mykhailo Skliar's Accepted answer below, and serparated the Datasource beans into a new Configuration class. Though it resolved the initial `Unresolveble circular reference` issue anymore, it led me to the following error:

```
Error creating bean with name 'springBatchConfig': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.BatchConfigurationException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jdbcUrl is required with driverClassName.
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49141541), I changed my url property names as follows:

```
spring.datasource.jdbc-url=

spring.datasource.jdbc-url=
```

Though it solved the jdbcUrl error, it posed another issue:

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Reference to database and/or server name in 'sample-sql-server.schema1.MY_TABLE_NAME' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Both my data sources are Azure SQL server instances.
I looked up and found it was not possible to use multiple Azure SQL databases years ago, but based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284998/cant-query-between-databases-in-sql-azure) it should not be the case anymore.

Comment: Take a look to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10132914/7343009

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is most probably because of

```
factory.setDataSource(batchDataSource());
```

You should use autowired bean here, instead of calling `batchDataSource()`

I would split **SpringBatchConfig** in two beans:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {



    @Bean(name = "batchDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.batchdatasource")
    public DataSource batchDataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "primaryDatasource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}






@Configuration
public class SpringBatchConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer{

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;


    @Qualifier("batchDataSource")
    @Autowired
    private DataSource batchDataSource;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;



    @Override
    public JobRepository createJobRepository() throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(batchDataSource);
    factory.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    factory.setTablePrefix("schema1"+ ".BATCH_");
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer was helpful, but it led me to another issue. I've updated the question. If you can help with that.

Comment: @Abhinandan Madaan I think it is better to create a separate question for this issue. It seems to be completely different issue, which is not related to the original. If you create a separate question, please, provide the link here, so I could also take a look, when I have time.

Comment: Fair. I'll mark your answer as "Accepted" since it solved my initial problem. I've posted the other issue as a separate question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68309042/reference-to-database-and-or-server-name-in-is-not-supported-in-this-version-of