# Fail to query from any database on Azure SQL Database

Tags: java, sql, azure

I try to connect to one of my Azure Database `jdbc:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433;database=Product`, I can query from Product.

Then I try to connect my Azure database `jdbc:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433` and fail to query from any database any table with error "Reference to database and/or server name is not supported in this version of SQL Server"

Is this related to cross database query mentioned in [Cross-Database Queries in Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/) ? If not, is there any method to do a connection to query from any database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't query between databases in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284998/cant-query-between-databases-in-sql-azure)

Comment: @tgdavies I have read this before. So if my function may query many difference database, then I need to create EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE for all the database I may reached?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Microsoft official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-java#prepare-a-configuration-file-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database), this is the standard and recommended way in configure file to connect with Azure SQL Database.

You can use environment variable to change the database name.

Set `database=YOUR_DB_NAME` and use the variable name in the URL:

`jdbc:sqlserver://***.database.windows.net:1433;${database}`